# zip error - Nothing to do

Tags: bash, shell

I try to zip all folders in given directory. So I wrote this

```
find /home/user/rep/tests/data/archive/* -maxdepth 0 -type d -exec zip -r "{}" \;
```

but got

```
zip error: Nothing to do! (/home/user/rep/tests/data/archive/tmp.zip)

zip error: Nothing to do! (/home/user/rep/tests/data/archive/tmp_dkjg.zip)
```

here is what this contains

```
user@machine:~$ ls /home/aliashenko/rep/tests/data/archive/
tmp  tmp_dkjg  tmp_dsf
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The issue is that you have not provided a name for the zip-files it will create.

```
find /home/user/rep/tests/data/archive/* -maxdepth 0 -type d -exec zip -r "{}" "{}" \;
```

This will create separate zipped directories for each of the subfolders `tmp`  `tmp_dkjg` and `tmp_dsf`

Answer (score 27):

### To create a zipfile:

- From a **list of files**, `zip myZippedImages.zip alice.png bob.jpg carl.svg`. You need to specify both

  - the zipfile (output), and
  - the files you  will zip (input).
- From a **folder**, `zip -r myZippedImages.zip images_folder`

---

To make it clearer than Alex's answer, to create a zip file, zip takes in a minimum of 2 arguments. How do I know, because when you use `man zip`, you get its man page, part of which is:

```
zip  [-aABcdDeEfFghjklLmoqrRSTuvVwXyz!@$] [--longoption ...]  [-b path]
       [-n suffixes] [-t date] [-tt date] [zipfile [file ...]]  [-xi list]
```

and when you typed `zip` in the command line, you get:

```
zip [-options] [-b path] [-t mmddyyyy] [-n suffixes] [zipfile list] [-xi list]
```

In both cases, notice `[zipfile list]` or `[zipfile [file ...]]`. The square brackets indicate something being **optional**. If you're not saving to a zipfile, then the `list` argument is not required.

If you want to save into a zipfile (choosing the `[zipfile list]` option, you need to also provide `list`, because it is within the square brackets. For this reason, I prefer the output of `zip` instead of `man zip`. (The man page might be confusing)

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps :

1. Use root user to confirm permissions
2. cd to the folder location
3. Use command zip -r [zip_file_name] [folder_name]/

Note: Do not use .zip with your zip file name. Also make sure you have zip and unzip installed by using apt or yum install zip and unzip

Answer (score 1):

If you used zip command on a zip file you will see that error.
make sure you are using zip on none zip version file, otherwise use unzip

Comment: i am facing similar issue:

i have to zip two files, and those file names are dynamic and its also possible only one file would exist.




so when i tried this way:

zip -r AllFiles.zip *.tgz *.zip. --> this is failing when either of the source is not found.

is it possible to handle this case? pls suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I tried below command

```
find /home/user/rep/tests/data/archive/* -maxdepth 0 -type d -exec zip -r "{}" "{}" \;
```

but got this,

```
find: ‘/home/Mitul/rep/tests/data/archive/*’: No such file or directory
```

Then i provided the name of zip file and it created the zip file,

```
zip -r <NAME FOR THE ZIP FILE WHICH WILL BE CREATED> <NAME OF THE FOLDER OR FOLDERS OR FILE OF WHICH YOU WANT TO MAKE A ZIP FILE>
```